# centering google map marker in thickbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, thickbox

I need to open a Google Map in a popup on my web page, for this I am using jquery Thickbox plugin.

There is a location marker on Google Map which I need to show in the center of that popup which will appear and containing Google Map.

Can somebody suggest me how to achieve this?

While I open the HTML file (which I call in Thickbox to open as a popup) it is appearing in perfect center but not in thick box.

Note: This is working fine in Google Chrome.

Is there any other way of calling Google Map into Thickbox? right now I am calling a different HTML into Thickbox.

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, Thickbox is no longer under development and I believe the developers advise the use of other similar utilities. See the comment at the top of: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the Google Map canvas is larger (wider / taller / both) than the thickbox window. This would produce an off-centre effect.

Try using Chrome's inspect element to see if the Google map's canvas div is completely contained within the popup.